# When and why does Java read an uninitialised final static variable without compiler or runtime errors?

Tags: java, static, constants, static-methods

In the following code, `readSide()` refers to `SIDE` and when invoked to initialise another static variable, appears to get a value of zero, rather than the value assigned in `SIDE`'s declaration.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class StaticTest {

    private final static float SIDE_FROM_METHOD = readSide();
    private final static float SIDE = 100.0f * new Random().nextFloat();

    private static float readSide() {
        System.out.println("In readSide(): SIDE=" + SIDE);

        return SIDE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("In main(): SIDE_FROM_METHOD=" + SIDE_FROM_METHOD);
        System.out.println("In main(): SIDE=" + SIDE);
        System.out.println("In main(): readSide() return=" + readSide());
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
In readSide(): SIDE=0.0
In main(): SIDE_FROM_METHOD=0.0
In main(): SIDE=85.84305
In readSide(): SIDE=85.84305
In main(): readSide() return=85.84305
```

So although `SIDE` is supposed to be a constant, Java allows it to change value at runtime, rather than either throwing an exception or ensuring that initialisation order is done in dependency order.

I believe the source of the problematic behavior is the order of defining the "final static" objects, but why doesn't it cause exception instead of working like that?

If `SIDE` is initialised to a literal rather than a calculated value:

```
private final static float SIDE=100.0f;
```

... then the output is `100.0` throughout.

```
In readSide(): SIDE=100.0
In main(): SIDE_FROM_METHOD=100.0
In main(): SIDE=100.0
In readSide(): SIDE=100.0
In main(): readSide() return=100.0
```

Why does this make a difference?

Comment: Can you include what you mean by the strange behaviour?

Comment: Why would it error?

Comment: @corriganjc Sample output has been added to the question.

Comment: I've taken quite a liberty by extensively rewriting your question and replacing the example. I hope you accept that it's asking the same question more clearly.

Comment: @slim That is OK, it is now easier to understand. It surprised me so :) .

Comment: @slim "dereferenced" is not correct for `long` (or any primitive variable type).

Comment: @Tom Well the variable refers to a value, so when you retrieve that value you are dereferencing. But I appreciate that "reference" has a special meaning in Java, so if you can suggest a better word (I rejected "use"), gimme (or just edit it yourself).

Comment: @slim yes "referencing" and "dereferencing" have a special meaning in Java (there is also a compiler error message when you try to call a method on a primitive ("can't be dereferenced")). But finding a better word ... that's a different story :D. How about a simple "access" or "read"?

Comment: @Tom "read" will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stumbled on some fairly subtle behaviour, hinging on the definition of a constant.

Most of the time we assume that any `final static` variable is a "constant", and this is good enough for us to get on with programming.

However the [Java Language Specification states in section 4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

(emphasis mine)

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final **and
>   initialized with a compile-time constant expression** (§15.28), is
>   called a constant variable.
>
> Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications
>   with respect to class initialization (§12.4.1), binary compatibility
>   (§13.1, §13.4.9) and definite assignment (§16).

... and we have to jump to another section to find out what they mean by "compile-time constant expression". In a nutshell though, `100.0f` is a compile-time constant expression. So is `100.0f * 10`. `100.0f * new Random().nextFloat()` is not, because it cannot be calculated at compile time.

In your first example, `SIDE` is not strictly a constant, and so initialisation happens in a different order - the details are in [JLS 12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

When you change the program to make `SIDE = 100f`, it becomes a bona-fide compile-time constant, and hence the rules change and it gets assigned at compile-time.

Once you know, it's easy to work around these issues. As you've observed, just putting the assignments in the right order will fix the symptoms.

Comment: You seem to have got the right answer but the idea about putting it on the constructor defeats the point of it being a (final static) and the code sample will surely not work. The only fix that I can think about is to make sure the order is right or to write this part in a static block of code.

Comment: @user2999069 You're right, the bit about constructors was a brainfart and I have removed it.

Answer (score 2):

The strange behaviour is caused by the fact that when `private final static float[] POINTS = generatePoints();` the `SIDE` constant has not been initialised. To fix the problem just move that line down to below the initialisation of `SIDE`.

The reason there is no exception is because `SIDE` will hold the value `0.0` before initialisation so all that goes wrong is that the calculations in `generatePoints` reads that value as `0`.

See [JLS 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) for what values are used for each type.

Comment: I understand that, but what I thought is that the value for SIDE is supposed to be undefined or defined and since it is a constant it should either have no value at all and this should cause error or defined with the right value, but for a constant to change value during the execution of the code! (This is the definition of unexpected behavior)

Comment: @user2999069 - In a perfect world that would be true. I've added a reference.

Comment: I understand the initial value of variables, but since this is a constant (final static float) I thought it shouldn't change value. I was using eclipse IDE and I used the feature source > sort members which arranges the methods and members alphabetically so this happened out of no where (I knew it was because of the order of execution but I expected the heads up from java if something like this was going to happen)

Comment: There is something more subtle here, since if I simplify the program to remove all the arrays and `Random`s, the "strange behaviour" doesn't occur.

Comment: @slim I think removing `Random` just obscures behaviour through compiler optimisation - it works "normally" when value can be determined at compile time (using `new Integer(1)` also reverts us to "strange" behaviour).

Comment: @slim removing the Random will probably allow optimization by the java compiler to inline the values of those constants or something similar. And the array can be replaced by any computation that depends on the constants but if removing it might cause compiler optimization to kick in.

Comment: I think these observations are correct, but compiler optimisation is not supposed to make programs behave differently unless the specs allow it. So there must be something in the JLS that explains this.

Comment: ... and it's https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4 - will put this in an answer.